# How do the files in HDFS and in local ext4 filesystems correspond to each other?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

How do the files in HDFS and in local ext4 filesystems correspond to each other?

According to [Do I have to create /tmp and /user/hive/warehouse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56121785/do-i-have-to-create-tmp-and-user-hive-warehouse)

> Both '/tmp' and '/user/hive/warehouse' directories are created in hdfs file system. You cannot see these folders using local file system commands.
>
> This `/tmp` folder in your local filesystem is maintained by your operating system and used to hold temporary files. Not related to hdfs.

I thought that

- the files in HDFS and the files in local ext4 filesystems are not the same files, and are independent to each other, except that maybe the files in HDFS are implemented in some other files in local ext4 filesystem.
- the HDFS filesystem by default should be empty without any file, and to add a file to it, I would have to add files to the HDFS filesystem , by using `hadoop fs` command.

But the following examples confuse me:

1. Example 1: [I found that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56121785/do-i-have-to-create-tmp-and-user-hive-warehouse)

   ```
   $ $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop fs -mkdir       /tmp
   mkdir: `/tmp': File exists
   ```

   and

   ```
   $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop fs -ls       /tmp
   ```

   shows the same files as `ls -l /tmp` in my local ext4 filesystem.

   Why does the HDFS filesystem by default contain the directory `/tmp`
   of my local ext4 filesystem, without me explicitly running `hadoop fs` to add `/tmp` to the HDFS filesystem?
2. Example 2:

   ```
   $ $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop fs -mkdir       /user/hive/warehouse
   mkdir: `/user/hive/warehouse': No such file or directory
   ```

   and there is no `/usr/hive/warehouse` in my local ext4 file system
   in my Ubuntu.

   If I create  `/usr/hive/warehouse`  in the HDFS filesystem

   ```
   $ sudo env "JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME" $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop fs -mkdir -p /user/hive/warehouse
   ```

   why does it also create `/user/hive/warehouse/` in my local ext4
   filesystem

   ```
   $ ls -ld /user/hive/warehouse/
   drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May 14 05:30 /user/hive/warehouse/
   ```

---

Does the answer to the above questions depend on whether my Hadoop is in Local Mode, Pseudodistributed Mode, and Distributed Mode?
If yes, how do the files in HDFS and in local ext4 filesystems correspond to each other  in Local Mode, Pseudodistributed Mode, and Distributed Mode respectively?

I have downloaded hadoop-3.1.2 in my Ubuntu with ext4 filesystems.

I heard

- HDFS can work in Local Mode, Pseudodistributed Mode, and Distributed Mode.
- by default, HDFS  works in Local Mode.

I haven't made any change to Hadoop's configurations, so I think HDFS works in local mode, although I would like to know how to check/verify that (how?).

Comment: Are you using `hadoop fs` or `hdfs fs`?  Because the output indicates either you've really messed up your configs, or you are using `hdfs fs` instead of `hdfs dfs`.

Comment: What are the differences between hadoop fs or hdfs fs? How can I find out if I am using hadoop fs or hdfs fs?